# issues with running a .sh file outside server

Tags: bash, matlab

I have shell script which collects user input and generate a json file from the input. The input file is then read by a compiled matlab program which then creates an output file and I use that output file to plot.

I'm working on a linux server where I installed matlab runtime. Everything works fine inside the server, once I try to access the site outside the server the .sh doesn't completely execute( it only echoes the first lines and stops).

```
#!/bin/sh
# script for execution of deployed applications
#
# Sets up the MATLAB Runtime environment for the current $ARCH and executes 
# the specified command.
#
exe_name=$0
exe_dir=`dirname "$0"`
echo "------------------------------------------"
if [ "x$1" = "x" ]; then
  echo Usage:
  echo    $0 \<deployedMCRroot\> args
else
  echo Setting up environment variables
  MCRROOT="$1"
  echo ---
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:${MCRROOT}/runtime/glnxa64 ;
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${MCRROOT}/bin/glnxa64 ;
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${MCRROOT}/sys/os/glnxa64;
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${MCRROOT}/sys/opengl/lib/glnxa64;
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH;
  echo LD_LIBRARY_PATH is ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH};
  shift 1
  args=
  while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
      token=$1
      args="${args} \"${token}\"" 
      shift
  done
  eval "\"${exe_dir}/main\"" $args
fi
exit
```

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "outside the server"?

Comment: the browser i was testing it with is installed in the server and everything work. when i use the browser installed in my pc, the .sh file can't be executed. i can access the site though using the pc browser

Comment: You would need to setup your web environment (possibly already done) and additional scripting to access the script across the internet.

Comment: What does it have to do with PHP?

Comment: Browsers don't run shell scripts. And a local machine executing bash or matlab scripts would still need both installed at the very least. This sounds more like a computing 101 question, than programming-related.

Answer (score 0):

Using a script located within your web service document root. As an example, this is a simple PHP file to run the shell script. The `chdir` path used is just an example:

```
<?php 
chdir('/var/www/yourdir');
$output = shell_exec('./matlab_setup.sh arg1');
```

Note that making the script accessible via the internet means *anyone using a browser can access it*, unless you introduce futher safeguarding.

Comment: Hi, sorry i feel like i'm failing to explain myself, thanks for your patience. I have something like your above code and it does work (when testing it inside the server) but failing when using a a browser that's not in the server

Comment: No worries. Sounds like it's a permissions or file path error. Have you checked your web server logs?